# Can I display ads out of the ad manager?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unityads

**Hi Everyone,**
I'm kinda new to unity so please don't bully me, so my question is simple can I display ads out of the ad manager because I want in each case something to happen like in some cases when an ad is skipped or fully watched a level loads up or in other cases nothing happens, etc...,
if there is an easy way to make this please tell me,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ads that you are talking about are rewarded ads you can go through the documentation of unity
https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/monetization/getting-started
You can find all your answers here! There will be methods for
Adisskippes and ad is completed  you can find everything there!